# swift factory for decodable type to one of possible results

Tags: swift, codable

Note: saw this question but doesn't seem to resolve the issue:
[Swift Dynamically choose Codable struct for JSON field value based on response type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60669472/swift-dynamically-choose-codable-struct-for-json-field-value-based-on-response-t)

I don't know the runtime type before hand since decoding from a network call response. So currently I am attempting to decode in a try/catch one after another, but I am looking for a more concise way to do that based on a common property which could be used for a theoretical "switch" to define the runtime type.

I know that they always have a field with a key which can be mapped to the final type so is there a trick to use here? I am thinking something along the lines of a union type holding one of the possible results. Here is the example code I have:

```
struct Result1: Codable {
  let resultType: String = "result1" // this is always the case in the JSON for this particular type of result
  ...
  let other fields which are unique to this type of result
}

struct Result2: Codable {
  let resultType: String = "result2" // always this field in the json for this result type
  ...
  let other fields which are unique to this type of result ...
}

... Lot's of other types ...

struct ResultN: Codable { 
  let resultType: String = "resultN"
 ....
}


// Now how to decode the "either Result1 or Result2 or .... ResultN
let value = try JSONDecoder().decode(????.self, from: data) // don't know what type it will be yet 
if value is Result1 { ... handle this case ... }
if value is Result2 { ... handle this case ... }
....
if value is ResultN { ..... }
```

Perhaps decode to a general Json dictionary and from there map to the correct type?

Note:

Considering this mechanism (but lots of boiler plate):

```
let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]
switch dict["resultType"] {
  case "result1" : ... decode to res1
  ...
   case "resultN" : .... decode to resN
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207841/decodable-for-json-with-two-structs-under-the-same-tag ? There is still the big "switch", but it's under an enum value, so "safer", and I don't know what you do "case "result1" : ... decode to res1", but it should at least just call on Deserialization (as I'm afraid that you'd call also JSONDecoder, so + the JSONSerialization at the beginning, that would be 2 deserializations)

Comment: Based on previous linked question/answer, the small difference being that the object is at the same level: https://pastebin.com/X66WTWHH so it's `self.holder = .named(try .init(from: decoder))` instead (might have been tricky, so I wrote a sample). If it works and the answer is satisfying, you might mark the question as duplicate.

Comment: Add `print("--> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")` and show us what
 json data you are getting, or at least a good sample. It may be as simple as using Optionals `?` to resolve your issue.

Comment: "...decoding from a network call response", do you know the request because that could tell you what kind of a response to expect?

Answer (score 0):

Using Dictionary of resultType to Codable maybe enough  (JSON Decoding runs twice to get `dict` and `value` )

```swift
let map: Dictionary<String, Codable.Type> = [
    "result1": Result1.self,
    "result2": Result2.self,
　　　　　　　　// ...
    "resultN": ResultN.self
]

let codable = map[dict["resultType"]]
let value = try! JSONDecoder().decode(codable!, from: data)
```